# C# Get all the id of the html tag and set inner text for <td></td> tag

Tags: c#

I have string html, I want to get all id name of tag in string html.
get string html in file text:

```
<tr>
    <td class="X8">
    </td>
    <td colspan="6" class="X9"></td>
    <td colspan="4" class="X12" id="closedate">
    </td>
    <td colspan="6" class="X9"></td>
    <td colspan="4" class="X12" id="startdate">
    </td>
    <td class="X8">
    </td>
    <td class="X8" colspan="3">
    </td>
    <td class="X8">
    </td>
    <td colspan="9" class="X9"></td>
    <td colspan="6" class="X15" id="totalpayment"></td>
    <td class="X8">
    </td>
    <td class="X8">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="X17">
    </td>
    <td class="X17" colspan="8">
    </td>
    <td class="X17" colspan="33">
    </td>
    <td class="X17">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="X17">
    </td>
    <td class="X17" colspan="8">
    <td class="X17" colspan="16">
    </td>
    <td class="X17">
    </td>
    <td colspan="9" class="X20"></td>
    <td colspan="6" class="X23" id="approvaldate"></td>
    <td class="X17">
    </td>
    <td class="X17">
    </td>
</tr>
```

expected results: 
closedate, startdate,totalpayment, approvaldate.
Then I want to set inner text for id name tag 
(Ex:`<td colspan="6" class="X23" id="approvaldate">2018/07/18</td>`)
Using c#.Help me, please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to look up html agility pack.

Comment: @AmitKumar I agree a link to [ask] is needed, but you could phrase it better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you post a question, it is expected that you post what you have tried so far and the point where you're having trouble. Otherwise it looks like you're wanting us to do your job for you for free, and it's not well received. It is a reason to downvote, as you can see here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Load it into an xml document, select the nodes by name or attribute.
Then extract the data yourself. It is customary to show specific input, expected output, what you have already tried, and what specific errors you get when your current posted version of your code has attempted a run. Or a specific compile time error. 

You have only posted HTML code, in a C# question. What C# code question do you have specifically? You don't know about XMLDocument? If you do, how did you use it? you don't know how to extract the data from the model you serialize the HTML into?

Comment: Load it into an xml document, select the nodes by attribute.Exactly, Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

What I am understood from your question is you need the id of all in string simple Example Created for you

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <input id="Name" type="text" name="Full Name" runat="server" />
   <input id="Email" type="text" name="Email Address" runat="server" />
   <input id="Phone" type="text" name="Phone Number" runat="server" />
</form>


foreach (var control in Page.Form.Controls)
{
    if (control is HtmlInputControl)
    {
        var htmlInputControl = control as HtmlInputControl;
        string controlName = htmlInputControl.Name;
        string controlId = htmlInputControl.ID;
    }
}
```

Another Approach:-

```
HtmlElement table =  testWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("TableID");
if (table != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement row in table.GetElementsByTagName("TR"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, Lavit. But i'm using the API, i will get a html string as above, then  i need the id of all in string.